# Не получается придумать оптимальный алгоритм решения, словарь в списке списка

Tags: python, списки, словари

Что необходимо: получать информацию из папки "музыка" о всех треках (название трека, путь к файлу, альбом, исполнитель, время воспроизведения).

Как подобрать оптимальный алгоритм?

Зашел в тупик, самый удачный вариант который у меня получился (но из словаря не получается ничего вытащить).

Как хотелось бы это видеть:

```
Rubber Soul (1965)
    1.  "Drive My Car" 2:25 (Е://Музыка/Для понедельника/песня_из_рекламы.mp3)
    2.  "Norwegian Wood (This Bird Has Flown)" 2:01 (Е://Музыка/norwegian_wood.mp3)
```

Как выводится сейчас:

```
Kurt_Vile_-_01_-_Freeway.mp3
music/Kurt_Vile_-_01_-_Freeway.mp3
{'album': None, 'artist': 'Kurt Vile', 'duration': 161.22775510204082, 'number_of_track': None}
Nine_Inch_Nails_-_01_-_999999.mp3
music/Nine_Inch_Nails_-_The_Slip/Nine_Inch_Nails_-_01_-_999999.mp3
{'album': 'The Slip', 'artist': 'Nine Inch Nails', 'duration': 85.1330612244898, 'number_of_track': '1'}
from tinytag import TinyTag
import os
```

Код:

```
def scan_of_folder():  #получаем список путей к файлу
    all_path_to_files_in_music = []
    tree = os.walk('music')
    for path, files, folders in tree:
        for files_in_folders in folders:
            all_path_to_files_in_music.append(os.path.join(path, files_in_folders))
    return all_path_to_files_in_music

def list_of_files():  #получаем список файлов
    all_files_in_music = []
    tree = os.walk('music')
    for path, files, folders in tree:
        for files_in_folders in folders:
            all_files_in_music.append(os.path.join(files_in_folders))
    return all_files_in_music



def get_song_info_from_mp3_tags(all_path_to_files_in_music): #получаем список словарей атрибутов к каждому файлу
    list_of_tags = []
    for get_tags in all_path_to_files_in_music: 
        info_from_tags = TinyTag.get(get_tags)
        tags = {
            'album': info_from_tags.album,         # album as string
            'artist': info_from_tags.artist,        # artist name as string
            'duration': info_from_tags.duration,      # duration of the song in seconds
            'number_of_track': info_from_tags.track,         # track number as string
            }

        list_of_tags.append(tags)
    return list_of_tags


def creating_of_final_list(list_of_files, all_path_to_files_in_music, song_info):  # объединяем все списки в один
    final_list = list(map(list, zip(list_of_files, all_path_to_files_in_music, song_info)))
    return final_list


def printing_of_result(final_list): # получаем список вида: имя файла, путь к файлу, словарь с атрибутами
    content_of_track_info = {}
    for track_info in final_list:
        for content_of_track_info in track_info:

                #content_of_track_info['key'] = 'value'
            print(content_of_track_info)
    #print(content_of_track_info.get('album'))




if __name__ == '__main__': 
    all_path_to_files_in_music = scan_of_folder()
    list_of_files = list_of_files()
    song_info = get_song_info_from_mp3_tags(all_path_to_files_in_music)
    final_list = creating_of_final_list(list_of_files, all_path_to_files_in_music, song_info)
    printing_of_result(final_list)
```

Comment: В чем суть вопроса? Как искать данные по списку словарей или что-то другое? Если вопрос о поиске в структуре данных, то лучше привести небольшой пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: 0
голос «против»
избранное
Что я хочу сделать: получать информацию из папки "музыка" о всех треках (название трека, путь к файлу, альбом, исполнитель, время воспроизведения). Код который привел ниже это одна из попыток (самая успешная)осуществить задуманное. Но похоже, что я изначально выбрал не правильный путь решения. Вопрос звучит как-то так: как бы вы это сделали? (Код не нужен, просто словами)

Comment: в чем конкретно возникла проблема? Ваша функция `get_song_info_from_mp3_tags()` разве не это делает?

Comment: Не совсем, она получает только только атрибуты в виде словаря, а необходимо ещё путь к файлу и название файла

Comment: Для того чтобы ответить на вопрос `"как бы вы это сделали? "` надо чётко понимать __что__ надо сделать... Сейчас у вас вопрос звучит так - мне надо получать информацию из папки "музыка" о всех треках - я это реализовал, но моя реализация работает _не так как мне надо_. Как вам надо вы так и не описали...

Comment: Прошу прощения. Как хотелось бы видеть вывод:Rubber Soul (1965)
    1.  "Drive My Car" 2:25 (Е://Музыка/Для понедельника/песня_из_рекламы.mp3)
    2.  "Norwegian Wood (This Bird Has Flown)" 2:01 (Е://Музыка/norwegian_wood.mp3)
    3.  "You Won't See Me" 3:18 (Е://Музыка/you_wont_see_me.mp3)
    4.  "Nowhere Man" 2:40 (Е://Музыка/you_wont_see_me.mp3)
    5.  "Think for Yourself" 2:16 (Е://Музыка/Лена/beatles.mp3)
    6.  "The Word" 2:41 (Е://Музыка/Beatles - Rubber Soul/The Word.mp3)

Comment: Как это выглядит сейчас: 
Kurt_Vile_-_01_-_Freeway.mp3
music/Kurt_Vile_-_01_-_Freeway.mp3
{'album': None, 'artist': 'Kurt Vile', 'duration': 161.22775510204082, 'number_of_track': None}
Nine_Inch_Nails_-_01_-_999999.mp3
music/Nine_Inch_Nails_-_The_Slip/Nine_Inch_Nails_-_01_-_999999.mp3
{'album': 'The Slip', 'artist': 'Nine Inch Nails', 'duration': 85.1330612244898, 'number_of_track': '1'}
Nine_Inch_Nails_-_08_-_Corona_Radiata.mp3
music/Nine_Inch_Nails_-_The_Slip/Nine_Inch_Nails_-_08_-

Comment: Не могу вытащить значения из словаря для каждого трека

Comment: сейчас попробую набросать решение...

Comment: Спасибо. Можно не код, а просто словами, например: с помощью такого-то метода использовать цикл итд. Не смог подходящий метод нагуглить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы поступил следующим образом:

1. сканировал указанную директорию рекурсивно при помощи цикла по

   ```
   glob.glob(r'Е:/Музыка/**/*.mp3')
   ```
2. читал бы все теги для каждого файла в словарь (для одного файла)
3. добавлял бы в этот словарь ключ `filename: "/full/path/to/file.mp3"`
4. собирал бы все эти словари в список словарей (для всех файлов)
5. записал бы результирующий список словарей в какую нибудь `NOSQL DB` (например `TinyDB`)

дальше при помощи поиска по `TinyDB` искал бы нужные мне данные и выводил бы их в нужном мне виде.

---

Реализация:

```
import re
import datetime as DT
from glob import glob
from tinytag import TinyTag
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query, where
from pathlib import Path

MUSIC_DB = r'D:\audio\music\music_db.json'
MUSIC_SEARCH_PATHS = (
  r'Е:/Музыка/**/*.mp3',
  r'Е:/Музыка/**/*.m4a'
)

def get_all_music_tags(search_paths=MUSIC_SEARCH_PATHS,
                       verbose=1):
    data = []
    for path in search_paths:
        for f in glob(path):
            if verbose > 0:
                print(f'parsing [{f}]')
            tags = TinyTag.get(f).as_dict()
            tags['filename'] = f
            if verbose > 1:
                print(tags)
            data.append(tags)
    return data

def cre_music_db(data, db_filename=MUSIC_DB):
    db = TinyDB(db_filename, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    ids = db.insert_multiple(data)
    return db

def format_row(row,
               fmt='{track} "{title}" {duration} ({filename})'):
    if '{duration}' in fmt and 'duration' in row:
        row['duration'] = str(DT.timedelta(seconds=round(row['duration'])))
    return fmt.format(**row)
#####################################

data = get_all_music_tags(MUSIC_SEARCH_PATHS, verbose=0)
db = cre_music_db(data)
#print('*' * 80)
q = Query()
qry = (q.title.search('allegro', flags=re.I)) & (q.album == 'Времена года') 
res = db.search(qry)
for row in res:
    print(format_row(row, fmt='{track} "{title}" {duration} ({filename})'))
```

Результат:

```
01 "Пришла весна (Allegro)" 0:03:46 (Е:\Музыка\classic\Vivaldi\Four.Seasons\01-Пришла весна (Allegro).mp3)
03 "Пасторальный танец (Allegro)" 0:03:55 (Е:\Музыка\classic\Vivaldi\Four.Seasons\03-Пасторальный танец (Allegro).mp3)
04 "Томительная жара (Allegro non molto). Птицы и ветер. Плач крестьянина (Allegro)" 0:04:20 (Е:\Музыка\classic\Vivaldi\Four.Seasons\04-Томительная жара (Allegro non molto). Птицы и ветер. Плач крестьянина (Allegro).mp3)
07 "Танец и песня крестьянина (Allegro)" 0:04:51 (Е:\Музыка\classic\Vivaldi\Four.Seasons\07-Танец и песня крестьянина (Allegro).mp3)
09 "Охота (Allegro)" 0:03:13 (Е:\Музыка\classic\Vivaldi\Four.Seasons\09-Охота (Allegro).mp3)
10 "Сильный ветер - от холода бегут и топают ногами (Allegro non molto)" 0:03:29 (Е:\Музыка\classic\Vivaldi\Four.Seasons\10-Сильный ветер - от холода бегут и топают ногами (Allegro non molto).mp3)
12 "На льду (Allegro)" 0:03:14 (Е:\Музыка\classic\Vivaldi\Four.Seasons\12-На льду (Allegro).mp3)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Утром попробую, как будет результат, напишу. А glob работает в windows?

Comment: @MrStepin, да, работает